# How to inject a scoped service in a Swashbuckle example response?

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I need to get a **scoped** service injected into an `IOperationFilter` but it won't work by c-tor:

```
class MyOperationFilter: IOperationFilter
{
   public MyOperationFilter(IMyService service) { }
}
```

it will give an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider site:

this is expected because only a **transient** service can get injected, **not a scoped one**.

So how can I get a scoped service injected in an `IOperationFilter`?

There's no example in the documentation or anywhere else. The examples **I've seen use transient not scoped services**.
In ASP.NET Core, a scoped service can get injected into the middleware by adding the service as parameter to the `Invoke` method. But Swashbuckle doesn't seem to have an extension to allow this.

Looking at the source code, I cannot see Swashbuckle to have a way to do this.

Comment: What about inject the IServiceProvider into ctor, and then later on resolve your scoped service with it?

Comment: @grinay I already mentioned that it won't work due to how dependency injection works in middleware in ASP.NET Core. I updated the question to be even more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with two methods:

1. Inject IHttpContextAccessor if we are talking about scoped service for user request, and then request the scoped service to request.

_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ICurrentIdentity>();

2.Inject IServiceProvider and create a new scope, and then request your scoped service, but it will not have references to the current request.

```
serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<MyScopedService>()
```

Comment: I'm getting `injection InvalidOperationException: A relational store has been configured without specifying either the DbConnection or connection string to use` I cannot share the code.

Comment: This is about wrong configured entity framework. Try to search with this error. Or share how exactly you’ve set connection string for it. Will try to help.

Comment: Thank you. I made a sample app and it works with IHttpConextAccessor, thank you. However, in the actual app, the injected instance of a custom configuration class is empty (hence the `InvalidOperationException` from my previous comment). It's a big app, and the DI makes it very hard to track down how exactly everything works. I haven't able to figure it out yet

Comment: I think the problem is that when `options.OperationFilter<MyFilter>()` is called by Swashbuckle, that service is not yet registered....